# Mac 10.9 kext file unloads randomly

Tags: macos, mac, kext, osx-mavericks, kernel-extension

I'm working with Mac 10.9 (Mavericks) and making a kernel extension (ported from 10.8). I load the kext file in the `/System/Library/Extension` folder but at times I will find the the kext gets unloaded randomly for no apparent reason. I will load it, and when I try to unload it 10 mins later, I will find that it is not loaded (and I have to load it again and unload it to test the outputs to make sure I'm still sane...).

Has anyone seen this problem or may know what are some possible reason that the OS may unload the kext randomly after some time but does accept loading it when the command is given??

Of course, I'm using this folder for backwards compatibility for earlier Mac OSX versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there are several issues with my kext, mainly due to a bug in the I/O Kit Personalities that made me believe that this topic was the issue but is not. Here is a note described by kext [implementation from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptAnatomy/kext_anatomy.html):

```
Loading behavior          Loaded automatically by the I/O Kit when needed
Unloading behavior        Unloaded automatically by the I/O Kit after a fixed interval when no longer needed
```

In this case, my kext gets loaded when first required and then unloaded once the properties are read and no longer needed.